# How I should make Ribbon icons smaller in Edit Form?

Tags: ribbon

I am looking for a way to make the ribbon icons smaller in my edit pop up form.

[image: This is the current ribbon item]

[image: This is the kind of ribbon that I want to have]

Because I am writing an online application for SharePoint 2013, I need to make this change by programming in the client side.

Comment: your image is not visible

Comment: I also couldn't see them in my google chrome. I installed android app for stack exchange and it shows my images. Seems lile an issue with the website or browser.

Comment: To put it in words, one shows normal delete icon with the text under it and another one shows the small delete icon with text beside it.

Comment: I guess there is no easy way for that, you could maybe change the css and add it to your masterpage